# Can't get JSON request from my local server in Ionic 4

Tags: php, angular, cordova, php-7, ionic4

I'm trying to get a JSON from my local php server into a ionic 4 application. First I discovered that I had to use "ionic cordova emulate browser" instead of "ionic serve" command in order to make HTTP work, since cordova is required. After this, I could reach a JSON example from jsonplaceholder website, but I still can't reach my local server. I tried all possible combinations of urls for my local server and I have no clue what to do next. The codes:

**tab1.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import { Tab1Service } from '../api/tab1/tab1.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {

  //v: requests from my local server
  v1: any;
  v2: any;
  v3: any;
  v4: any;
  v5: any;

  //a: requests from other server
  a1: any;
  a2: any;

  constructor(public http: HTTP, public tab1Service:Tab1Service) {

    //My server
    //With HTTP -------------
    //Set v1
    this.http.get('http://192.168.0.21/WebServer/Ionic/process.php', {}, {})
    .then(res => {
      this.v1 = res.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(err => 
      this.v1 =  err
    );

    //Set v2
    this.http.get('192.168.0.21/WebServer/Ionic/process.php', {}, {})
    .then(res => {
      this.v2 = res.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(err => 
      this.v2 =  err
    );

    //Set v3
    this.http.get('http://localhost/WebServer/Ionic/process.php', {}, {})
    .then(res => {
      this.v3 = res.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(err => 
      this.v3 =  err
    );

    //Set v4
    this.http.get('localhost/WebServer/Ionic/process.php', {}, {})
    .then(res => {
      this.v4 = res.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(err => 
      this.v4 =  err
    );

    //With HttpClient ---------------
    //Set v5
    this.tab1Service.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data) => this.v5 = data['dados']);

    //Other server
    //With HTTP -------------
    //Set a1
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {}, {})
    .then(res => {
      this.a1 = res.data;
      }
    )
    .catch(err => 
      this.a1 =  err
    );

    //With HttpClient ---------------
    //Set a2
    this.tab1Service.getConfig2()
    .subscribe((data) => this.a2 = data['title']);
  }
}
```

**PS:** All the urls combinations work in the browser

**tab1.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Tab1Service {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get('http://192.168.0.21/WebServer/Ionic/process.php');
  }

  getConfig2() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
}
```

**process.php**

```
<?php 
$result = "{ \"success\": true, \"dados\": \"teste\" }";              

//Echo $result and set headers
echo $result;
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

**PS:** I have the same problem with and without these headers

Prints:

- [Tab One page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPA45.png): I print all the variables in the same order that they appear in **tab1.module.ts** in Tab One Page (I created the ionic tab project)
- [JSON output from both servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0epAd.png)
- [Response Headers from both servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGewI.png)
- [Console error output when setting v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DScPg.png): This error seems to be related to HttpClient function

Versions:

- PHP 7 with Apache Lounge
- Ionic 4.10.3
- Cordova 8.1.2

Everything I did was based on internet tutorials since I'm pretty new to ionic and php.

**EDIT 1**

The images information as text:

- **Tab One page output** (Vs {{v1}}, {{v2}}, {{v3}}, {{v4}}, {{v5}} | As {{a1}}, {{a2}})

  Vs
    [object Object],
    [object Object],
    [object Object],
    [object Object],  |

  As
    { "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": 
    false },
    delectus aut autem
- **JSON from both servers**

  *My server*

  { "success": true, "dados": "teste" }

  *jsonplaceholder*

  {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
  }
- **Response Headers from both servers**

  *My server*

  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Length: 37
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 14:55:59 GMT 
  Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
  Server: Apache/2.4.38 (Win64) PHP/7.3.3
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.3

  *jsonplaceholder*

  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
  CF-Cache-Status: HIT
  CF-RAY: 4ba06d22bfc3ba18-ATL
  Connection: keep-alive
  Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 15:19:43 GMT
  Etag: W/"53-hfEnumeNh6YirfjyjaujcOPPT+s"
  Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn- 
  cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
  Expires: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 19:19:43 GMT
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: cloudflare
  Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
  Via: 1.1 vegur
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-Powered-By: Express
- **Console error**

  ERROR {…} ​error: error​​bubbles: false​​cancelBubble: false​​cancelable: false​​ 
    composed: (...)​ message: "Http failure response for 
    http://192.168.0.21/WebServer/Ionic/process.php: 0 Unknown Error"​ name: 
    "HttpErrorResponse"​ok: false​status: 0​ statusText: "Unknown Error" ​url: 
    "http://192.168.0.21/WebServer/Ionic/process.php"​

**EDIT 2**

Guys, I found what was wrong with my request. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was missing. So, when I added:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

in the end of **process.php**, it worked.

**EDIT 3**

**IMPORTANT:** I've just learned that if you add this header you actually put your server in risk, since it becomes more vulnerable to CSRF attack and other similar attacks. So, the right thing to do is to add the specific origins that need to access the server and not use * as a value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: Please post your errors as text. As someone behind a proxy, I can't help you at the moment.

Comment: In addition to @trichetriche, imgur.com is forbidden in my country (don't ask why :) ). So I can't help either

Comment: @HarunYılmaz I feel your pain, at least tell me you have pr0n :D

Comment: Now the images information is in text too : )